# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable - No gradients in GANs generator model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm currently coding a GAN to generate sequences. Both the generator and the discriminator are working, when trained standalone. As soon as I combine both to the complete GAN model (to train the generator with discriminators weights frozen) the following error occurs and the graph seems to be not connected between generator and discriminator.

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['generator_lstm/kernel:0', 'generator_lstm/recurrent_kernel:0', 'generator_lstm/bias:0', 'generator_softmax/kernel:0', 'generator_softmax/bias:0'].

At first i thought my custom activation function was causing the issue. But since it works standalone i think the both "submodels" are not connected correctly. Im not sure if its important, but in the tensorboard graph there is no connection between both models.

[Tensorboard Graph to my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjJyL.png)

The error occurs on exactly the last line of the train() function.
I already tried TF versions 2.1 and 2.4.1, it makes no difference.

```
# softargmax and build[...]() functions are located in my "gan" python module
# custom softargmax implementation 
@tf.function
def softargmax(values, beta = 1000000.0):

    # tf.range over all possible indices
    range_tensor = tf.range(54, dtype=tf.float32)
    range_tensor = tf.reshape(range_tensor, [-1, 1])

    # softmax activation of (input*beta)
    values = tf.cast(values, dtype=tf.float32)
    beta = tf.cast(beta, dtype=tf.float32)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(((values*beta) - tf.reduce_max(values*beta)))
    return softmax @ range_tensor

callable_softargmax = tf.function(softargmax)
get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(callable_softargmax)})

def build_generator(z_dim, seq_len, num_of_words):

    gen_input = Input(shape=(z_dim,), name="generator_input")
    gen_repeat = RepeatVector(seq_len, name="generator_repeat")(gen_input)
    gen_lstm = LSTM(128, activation="relu", return_sequences=True, name="generator_lstm")(gen_repeat)
    gen_softmax = Dense(num_of_words, name="generator_softmax")(gen_lstm)
    #gen_activation = tf.keras.layers.Activation(callable_softargmax)(gen_softmax)
    gen_soft_argmax = Lambda(callable_softargmax, name="generator_soft_argmax")(gen_softmax)
    generator = Model(gen_input, gen_soft_argmax, name="generator_model")
    generator.summary()
    return generator


def build_discriminator(seq_len, num_of_words, embedding_len):

    embedding = np.load(PATH + MODELS + "embedding_ae.npy")
    discriminator = Sequential(name="gan_discriminator")
    discriminator.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(seq_len,1), name="discriminator_input"))
    discriminator.add(Reshape(target_shape=[18,], dtype=tf.float32, name="discriminator_reshape"))
    discriminator.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_of_words, output_dim=embedding_len, input_length=seq_len, mask_zero=False,
                         embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(embedding), trainable=False, name="discriminator_emb"))
    discriminator.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid", recurrent_dropout=0, unroll=False, use_bias=True,
                                         return_sequences=True), name="discriminator_lstm"))
    discriminator.add(Dropout(0.2, name="discriminator_dropout"))
    discriminator.add(LSTM(128, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid", recurrent_dropout=0, unroll=False, use_bias=True,
                           name="discriminator_lstm2"))
    discriminator.add(Dropout(0.2, name="discriminator_dropout2"))
    discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="discriminator_output"))
    discriminator.summary()

    return discriminator


def build_gan(generator, discriminator):
    gan = Sequential(name="gan")
    gan.add(generator)
    gan.add(discriminator)

    return gan

def train(train_data, generator, discriminator, gan, iterations, batch_size, z_dim):
   
    real = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

    for iteration in range(iterations):
        idx = np.random.randint(0, train_data.shape[0], batch_size)
        train_samples = train_data[idx]
        train_samples = np.reshape(train_samples, [batch_size, 18, 1])

        # train discriminator
        z = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, z_dim))
        z = np.reshape(z, [batch_size, z_dim])
        gen_samples = generator.predict(z)

        d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(train_samples, real)
        d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_samples, fake)
        d_loss, accuracy, = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

        # train generator
        z = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, z_dim))
        gen_samples = generator.predict(z)
        g_loss = gan.train_on_batch(z, real)

# compiling and running models in main.py
discriminator = gan.build_discriminator(seq_len=18, num_of_words=54, embedding_len=200)
discriminator.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=["accuracy"])
discriminator.trainable = False
    
generator = gan.build_generator(z_dim, seq_len=18, num_of_words=54)


gan_model = gan.build_gan(generator, discriminator)
gan_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001))

gan.train(train_data=train, generator=generator, discriminator=discriminator,
          gan=gan_model, iterations=iterations, batch_size=batch_size, z_dim=z_dim)


Model: "gan_discriminator"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
discriminator_reshape (Resha (None, 18)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
discriminator_emb (Embedding (None, 18, 200)           10800     
_________________________________________________________________
discriminator_lstm (Bidirect (None, 18, 256)           336896    
_________________________________________________________________
discriminator_dropout (Dropo (None, 18, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
discriminator_lstm2 (LSTM)   (None, 128)               197120    
_________________________________________________________________
discriminator_dropout2 (Drop (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
discriminator_output (Dense) (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 544,945
Trainable params: 534,145
Non-trainable params: 10,800
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "generator_model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
generator_input (InputLayer) [(None, 128)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
generator_repeat (RepeatVect (None, 18, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
generator_lstm (LSTM)        (None, 18, 128)           131584    
_________________________________________________________________
generator_softmax (Dense)    (None, 18, 54)            6966      
_________________________________________________________________
generator_soft_argmax (Lambd (None, 18, 1)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 138,550
Trainable params: 138,550
Non-trainable params: 0

_________________________________________________________________
Model: "gan"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
generator_model (Model)      (None, 18, 1)             138550    
_________________________________________________________________
gan_discriminator (Sequentia (None, 1)                 544945    
=================================================================
Total params: 683,495
Trainable params: 138,550
Non-trainable params: 544,945
_________________________________________________________________
```

Do you have any suggestions on the model and what might possibly be wrong?